# boost string split to eliminate spaces in words

Tags: c++, string, boost, split

I have written this code to split up a string containing words with many spaces and/or tab into a string vector just containing the words.

```
#include<iostream>       
#include<vector>                        
#include<boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>       
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>                         
int main()                              
{                  
    using namespace std;                                     

    string str("cONtainS            SoMe    CApiTaL WORDS");       

    vector<string> strVec;              
    using boost::is_any_of;       

    boost::algorithm::split(strVec, str, is_any_of("\t "));       

    vector<string>::iterator i ;       

    for(i = strVec.begin() ; i != strVec.end(); i++)       
        cout<<*i<<endl;              

    return 0;                                             
}
```

I was expecting an output

```
cONtainS
SoMe
CApiTaL
WORDS
```

but i m geting output with space as an element in the strVec i.e

```
cONtainS











SoMe



CApiTaL
WORDS
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add a final parameter with the value `boost::token_compress_on`, as per the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html):

```
boost::algorithm::split(strVec,str,is_any_of("\t "),boost::token_compress_on);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because your input contains consecutive separators. By default `split` interprets that to mean they have empty strings between them.

To get the output you expected, you need to specify the optional `eCompress` parameter, with value `token_compress_on`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id667600.html